# Unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body deprecated; How to find in project?

Tags: google-chrome, data-uri

I'm getting this warning from Chrome in my Angular 2+ application. Ok, so how am I supposed to go about finding where this issue is occurring in my project with so many data URIs? Wait for it to fail, I suppose? Yikes.

> [Deprecation] Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is
>   deprecated and will be removed in M67, around May 2018. Please use
>   '%23' instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more
>   details.

Seems like they should point to the source somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here, updated to M67, but now it says that it wil be removed in M68. In my case, I believe jquery-validation plugin has something to do with it, of jquery itself, not quite sure yet.

Answer (score 8):

If you have inline SVG, look at color references and replace #rrggbb with rgb(R, G, B). It should help.

Source: https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2379

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, I noticed that the message was fired when filling a input. So I came up with jquery-validation, disabling it didn't fire the message.

Finally I found out that it is in the bootstrap framework. When an input is validated, a checkbox or cross is added to the HTML. This is done base on a SVG, which holds an attribute `fill='#3cb85c'`

The hashtag in the fill attribute triggers the message in my situation! Changing the `#` to `%23` fixes the issue.

Comment: Does anyone know what exactly the "deprecation" entails? I can't imagine that something breaks when visiting a web app/site if #'s are not replaced in Chrome...?