# How can I use %23 instead of # in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, warnings, hashtag

How can I use `%23` instead of `#` in Chrome?

html:

```
<div class="helloText">
hello text
</div>
```

css:

```
.helloText {
    background: #FF8500 url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'><polygon points='0,1 1,1 1,0' style='fill:#fff;'></polygon></svg>" );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 36px 36px;
    background-position: 100% 100%;

    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 35px;

    color: white;
    font-family: AvenirLT65Medium;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

res

[image]

In such a configuration everything works fine. The only but is that I am getting the following warning in Chrome console:

> [Deprecation] Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is deprecated and will be removed in M71, around December 2018. Please use '%23' instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more details.

Ok, let me change css to:

```
.helloText {
        background: #FF8500 url( "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' preserveAspectRatio='none'><polygon points='0,1 1,1 1,0' style='fill:%29fff;'></polygon></svg>" );
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 36px 36px;
        background-position: 100% 100%;

        padding: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        margin-top: 35px;

        color: white;
        font-family: AvenirLT65Medium;
        font-size: 14pt;
    }
```

res

[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/725/) is a fiddle. So, how do I substitute `#` to `%29`?

Also, I would like to notice that the part of an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615029/unescaped-characters-in-a-data-uri-body-deprecated-how-to-find-in-project) is wrong.

It tells that

> The hashtag in the fill attribute triggers the message in my situation! Changing the # to %23 fixes the issue.

But it is not the case as I explained above.

Comment: You could just use the color name instead of the hexa code. This way you won't have any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using SVG when you can easily do this with simple CSS:

```css
.helloText {
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#fff 50%),
   #FF8500;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 36px 36px;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-family: AvenirLT65Medium;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="helloText">
  hello text
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.helloText` will do the following: take a 36px square, move it to the right lower corner of the parent. Then the square will be divided into two parts by the diagonal which goes from the right upper corner to the left lower corner. of the squre. After such a division the upper part will be made transparent and the lower part will be made `#fff`. Am I right? I just never used the `linear-gradient` and thank to you read [the](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) articles, but it does not help to understand what is happening here.

Comment: And is the order of the values in background property important?

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov yes exactly,  it's like this ;) and yes the order is important when you have different background BUT when you use a single color it will always be the final layer (the bottom one) .. so the color can be used anywhere, the order will only have effect in case you consider many gradient or gradient with image, etc

Answer (score 3):

You used *%29* instead of *%23*. Using *%23*, it works as intended.